# Mutating specific variables based on columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have what I view to be a relatively easy question.  I'm looking to create a general function that mutates specific columns depending on whether the `df` has that particular column.

Not every `df` will have all of the columns under the mutate.

```
if(data %>% tibble::has_name(c("col1", "col2")) {

data <- data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars (one_of("col1", "col2", "col3"), list(~ifelse(. >1, ./ 1000, .)))

}
```

The way I have it currently written, gives me an error message:

```
Warning message:
In if (data %>% tibble::has_name(c("col1, "col2"))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Am I going about solving this problem the correct way?

Comment: The reason that your condition doesn't work is that `tibble::has_name()` returns a vector of results, one for each possible name, and so R simply takes the first value from the vector, ie whether `df` has a column called `col1`.

Comment: This is because your if is return two logical values.  You need to put something like all(data %>% tibble::has_name(c("col1", "col2))) that will verify if all values are TRUE, i.e, the data frame has the two columns?

Comment: Try this: `if (all(c("col1", "col2") %in% names(df)) == T){
   ## mutate columns
 }`

Comment: If you don't mind getting (or suppresing) a warning when there are no matching columns, you can leave out the `if` completely and just call `mutate_at` with the desired columns.

Comment: I want the condition to check if the data has either one of, or all of the columns.  I'm guessing all wouldn't work if the data doesn't have all of the listed columns, correct?

Comment: sms- I think a version of your solution would work, but I would switch "all" to "any".  That way if any column is in the df, you can proceed with the mutate based on the ifelse criteria.